# Property or method "moment" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property

Tags: laravel, jalali-calendar

moment Vue warn]: Property or method "moment" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See

```
methods:{
    toDate(date){
        return moment(date).format('jYYYY/jMM/jDD H:m');
    }
}
```

in

```
   <info-block class="mb-0" label="تاریخ پیام" icon="flip-to-back" :value="toDate(item.sms_list[0].created_at)" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just need to import

```
 import moment, { now } from "jalali-moment";
```